# Do agent/controller objects (nothing is referring to them) get released (Objective-C, ARC)?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am writing a singleton that will be instantiated in the AppDelegate, but I don't need a reference from AD to it. It is a controller reacting to app state changes.

Since it's not sitting on the main reference tree, will it be auto-released on the next pass (or however it's called when auto-releasing of objects occurs)?

Comment: How are you instantiating it? Are you assigning it to a static variable? Anywhere?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Neil Daniels pointed out, I am assigning the singleton instance to a static var, which should preserve the object from being released.